# No Traceback From Django when DEBUG True

Tags: django

I'm running under Fastcgi on Nginx. I have DEBUG = True, and I get the normal Django debug page when I go to an incorrect url on my site.

However I have an Ajax call being made via jQuery and it returns "An unhandled exception was thrown by the application." instead of a Django traceback. I really can't figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

```
def FetchItem(request):
    mimetype = 'application/json'
    item_list = simplejson.loads(request.POST['item_list'])
    auth = functions.auth_session_check(request)
    if auth:
        response = [functions.item_by_id(itemid) for itemid in item_list]
    else:
        response = []
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response), mimetype)
```

Comment: Is there some specific solution you are using in your app? Maybe it catches all the exceptions and generates AJAX-friendly message without respecting `DEBUG` setting?

Comment: Please post your view here, it will be easier to understand after looking at your code

Comment: Are you using firebug or chromes version "developer tools"?

Comment: I have updated the question with my view. I'm using Chromes developer tools, no Firebug.

Comment: I figured out the error, it was in the functions.auth_session_check() function. But I still don't know why django wasn't sending back an error page?

Answer (score 2):

The server would have returned the usual debug page with trackback and other information. But as it was ajax call, content of that page was not shows on the browser.

You can try doing non-ajax call by directly accessing that url.

Or check in response data for ajax request in some developer tool like goolgle chromes developer tool.

Comment: Thanks but I already tried that. I created a POST form in HTML and manually submitted it and I got the same "unhandled exception" error.